# KeyEvent stop Listening JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, keyevent

I have a very simply KeyEvent:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    Group root = new Group();
    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas( 900, 700 );

    scene.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(KeyEvent ke) {

            switch (ke.getCode()) {
                case UP:
                    System.out.println("UP");
                    break;
                case DOWN:
                    System.out.println("DOWN");
                    break;
                case LEFT:
                    System.out.println("LEFT");
                    break;
                case RIGHT:
                    System.out.println("RIGHT");
                    break;
                case ENTER:
                    //ke.consume();
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }});
```

What I like to reach:
I start to run the program and If I press the up, down, left, right the output write back to me UP,DOWN,LEFT,RIGHT ( It's correct no problem ).
But! If I press the enter, after If I will press the up, down, left, right, enter or another keys don't write back the output the UP,DOWN,LEFT,RIGHT.

So I liket to stop the KeyEvent "running" when I press the ENTER button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several opportunities, these two came two my mind first.

**1) Store the listener of your key event as a member of your class, and on ENTER press unregister it.**

```
private EventHandler<KeyEvent> keyHandler;


@Override
public void start(Stage stage) {
    final Scene scene = new Scene(new Group());
    stage.setTitle("Table View Sample");
    stage.setWidth(450);
    stage.setHeight(500);

    keyHandler = new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(KeyEvent ke) {

            switch (ke.getCode()) {
                case ENTER:
                    scene.removeEventHandler(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, keyHandler);
                    break;
                case UP:
                    System.out.println("UP");
                    break;
                case DOWN:
                    System.out.println("DOWN");
                    break;
                case LEFT:
                    System.out.println("LEFT");
                    break;
                case RIGHT:
                    System.out.println("RIGHT");
                    break;


                default:
                    break;
            }
        }};

   scane.addEventHandler(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, keyHandler);
```

**2) On ENTER press, store a boolean to a member, and if this member is set, consume the event.**

```
private Boolean enterPressed = false;

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) {
    final Scene scene = new Scene(new Group());
    stage.setTitle("Table View Sample");
    stage.setWidth(450);
    stage.setHeight(500);

   scene.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(KeyEvent ke) {

            if(enterPressed){
                ke.consume();
                return;
            }

            switch (ke.getCode()) {
                case ENTER:
                    enterPressed = true;
                    break;
                case UP:
                    System.out.println("UP");
                    break;
                case DOWN:
                    System.out.println("DOWN");
                    break;
                case LEFT:
                    System.out.println("LEFT");
                    break;
                case RIGHT:
                    System.out.println("RIGHT");
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }
        }});
```

Both are working, choose whatever you like.

Comment: Thank you so much! I saved my day O.O